# Hdmi splitter to monitor

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

How do u connect a laptop to 2 monitors with a hdmi splitter and not have the screens be duplicated, I want them to be extended. I have tried extending it but it just extends to my laptop! It extends one monitor to the laptop but I want both monitors and no laptop to be extended.

Comment: An hdmi splitter won't do that, the graphics interface in your laptop must support extending the desktop, usually using 2 hdmi outputs.

Answer (score 2):

It probably isn't possible with an HDMI splitter.  In general, in order to extend the desktop, you have to have each monitor on a separate connection to the graphics card, and even then the graphics card must support it.  As far as the laptop is concerned, the HDMI splitter most likely appears only as a single output.