# Laptop has one HDMI port and USB 2.0 Ports - Want to extend 2 monitors - each has Display Port and HDMI only

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Laptop has one HDMI port and USB 2.0 Ports - Want to extend 2 monitors- each has  Display Port and HDMI ports only.

I am limited by slow USB 2.0 port.

How can I extend my displays without a USB 3 port which I think I would need to get a HDMI to USB converter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hdmi splitter to monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/928416/hdmi-splitter-to-monitor)

Comment: no i can use an usb to hdmi adapter - if i had usb 3 but dont think i can with usb 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get video output from the USB, but you can use an HDMI splitter.

Comment: but i want to extend the displays not repeat them

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t need fast visuals or high GPU power, you can go for a DisplayLink adapter. They are also available for USB 2.0, though performance will obviously be *very* limited. It needs quite some RAM, too.

DisplayLink works by sending a compressed image stream through USB which is then converted to HDMI/DisplayPort/whatever as required.

There is no other solution.

Comment: So I will go with a DVI to USB adapter for one monitor and use the native HDMI connector to the other monitor and I can extend the displays.  Only issue is USB 2.0 lowers the quality of the video speed but I am not doing any video with this DVI to USB adapted screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually buy a new desktop computer since you will then able to add a better video card with multiple ports if your computer does not come with a good video card.

Then you can use your laptop when you travel.

Comment: Yes, that's ideal.  Looking into desktop system with good video card.